# Is it topical to ask if a site/project is "alive" on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope

I read the help and found it ambiguous whether or not it's topical to ask if a site is alive on Stack Overflow or not. The large number of successful questions asking if specific projects were alive suggests that when dealing with specific projects providing source code or libraries, such questions regarding liveness are topical. On the other hand, some questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062056/is-firebird-still-alive) one were considered too localized.

I more importantly don't have any frame of reference for asking about meta-information projects, such as sites that are supposedly carrying up-to-date information on the latest projects (ex. 'dsource.org', which seems questionably dead).

Are questions about site liveness acceptable on Stack Overflow? If so, what kinds of questions regarding what kinds of sites are acceptable on Stack Overflow with regards to said site's liveness? Does topicality change dependent on project vs. meta-project/collection-of-related-projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is no longer on topic for Stack Overflow. The definition of the scope of Stack Overflow has changed drastically over the years and as a result, some questions still linger from the past which are currently off-topic, but which were not when they were asked.

There are a couple reasons these are off topic:

- Nobody can be the definitive judge of a site's aliveitiveness
- There are many definitions for site and project activity
- Unless it is about a tool directly related to programming, it is off topic
- Even so, it can't simply be an arbitrary programming tool question; it has to be a problem you face (or could potentially face)

Please flag these questions as you see them if they are still open.

Comment: Sites can also be revived... So that falls into the ol' too localized category...

Comment: Awesome! 7777 rep.